# jQuery attr call not being applied to content as user scrolls and more content loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, reddit

I am trying to build a Google Chrome extension that blocks some images in posts from a user's Reddit feed based on some computer vision criteria that run in a Python back-end. I have found a way using jQuery to query the Reddit JSON and insert a `replacementImage` in place of the existing post image (code below), but the current block I am hitting is that when the user scrolls the page, the jQuery attr call does not impact posts/images down the page (i.e., after more posts load).

```
var replacementImage = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/CENSORED.JPG" 
$('img[alt="Post image"]').attr("src",replacementImage)
```

Comment: because that jquery script runs only ones when the page is loaded for all elements that are available at the moment, you need to add some event on new posts loading and put that script there

Comment: Thanks @svyatis.lviv , that fixed it. I was able to add an event listener to my content.js script in the chrome extension framework to trigger the code every time the user scrolls. I.e., 
```window.addEventListener("scroll", function() { /*mycode*/ } ```

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped.